# What kind of band stop circuitry is this?

Tags: analog, active-filter

I have found this band stop circuitry:

[image: band stop circuitry in LTSpice]

It gives this transmission function:

[image: Transmission]

It has a band stop behavior at 230Hz. The last opamp is a simple high amplifying lowpass. The first opamp feedback gives a lead compensator behavior. But especially the feedback over C9, R5, C11, R6, C12 is very unclear to me.

Have you ever seen this topology? I have searched the web for various kinds of band stops, but I have not found anything similar.

Does this circuit look familiar to you? If so, how do I calculate it? I mean I can use LTSpice to adjust the values by trial and error to my needs, but I want to understand what I am doing :)

Thanks in advance for your help!

**Update**

The second Opamp feedback loop is obviously a simple lowpass filter. Here I want to add some details to the first opamp feedback loops:

Taking only one feedback loop at the first opamp, like this

[image]

We get a typical lead compensator (https://ctms.engin.umich.edu/CTMS/index.php?aux=Extras_Leadlag) behavior in the transmission:

[image]

If we now add the second feedback loop, like this

[image]

We get this notch, high pass like behavior:

[image]

Whereas, this is not a real highpass. For a highpass for low frequencies, the amplitude should drop to -infinity dB. Here it stays at 0 dB. Strange

Can someone help me to calculate the transfer function of this circuitry? Or give me a good tutorial to calculate the transfer function for such kind of circuits?

Thank you very much

**Question of Ady aka:**
What happens when you delete resistor R5:

A highpass filter like behavior
[image]

Comment: What changes if you remove R5 and left C9 disconnected?

Comment: Instead of an band stop, you get a highpass filter like behavior. I will edit a picture into the question.

Comment: How can C11 and C12 provide a path for low-frequency signals?

Comment: Hey LvW, 
please dont ask me :)
Especially this feedback loop irritates me.

Comment: True. Thank you for the remark. @Andyaka I have added the resulting picture above.

Comment: @LvW ... I have seen in your other posts, that you have experience in calculating the transfer function for circuits. I am trying to learn that. And at least for simple opamp feedback loops I seem to get the point. Anyhow I have no clue to treat this double feedback system. I even tried SapWin. But the result was not reasonable. Can you help me here?

Comment: Sapwin is good for finding the transfer function (ideal or simplified 1st-order model for opamps). What really is your problem?

Comment: @LvW: I implemented it in SapWin. And the program calculated a transfer function for me. But when I tested the tf in Matlab, it was not the right one, by means it didn't look at all like the ones here calculated in LTSpice. My problem in general is here that I want to adapt the bandstop filter here for new sensors (need a different notch freq and width). Of course I can start playing around in LTSpice to get sth that might fit. But I would prefer to get an analytical expression. Then I would understand what values need to change. So basically I would like to understand the circuit :)